# SQLCMD PowerShell needs to return only value (without header)

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Running the following sqlcmd in PowerShell:

```
$unassignedCnt = sqlcmd -W -k 1 -S MSSQLSERVER -E -Q "SET NoCount ON; SELECT   Count(DISTINCT SP.SubnetKey) AS 'UnassignedCount' FROM [Control].[dbo].[Subnet] AS SP Left OUTER JOIN [Control].[rw_current].[QIP_Subnet] AS Q ON SP.KeyHash = Q.__key_Hash; SET NoCount OFF; "
Write-Host $unassignedCnt
```

This returns the following formatted result:

```
UnassignedCount --------------- 1
```

I would like to have only:

```
1
```

Can I achieve this through the SQL command or do I need to post process the result? If so what's the simplest approach?

Comment: `Write-Host $unassignedCnt` -> `Write-Host $unassignedCnt.UnassignedCount`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - That returns null

Comment: Unlikely. What is the output of `$unassignedCnt.GetType().FullName`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - System.Object[]

Comment: `$unassignedCnt` -> `$unassignedCnt[0].UnassignedCount`. Adjust the index if the first item is not the one you want.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - "Write-Host unassignedCnt[0].UnassignedCount" still returns null. Tried a few different index values and always null returned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150931/discussion-between-dross-and-ansgar-wiechers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using by changing your SQL query to use `PRINT` instead of `SELECT`

SELECT will create a table which has header and data associated with it.
PRINT simply outputs the results.

```
$unassignedCnt = sqlcmd -W -k 1 -S MSSQLSERVER -E -Q "SET NoCount ON; DECLARE @result varchar(max); SELECT  @result= Count(DISTINCT SP.SubnetKey) FROM [Control].[dbo].[Subnet] AS SP Left OUTER JOIN [Control].[rw_current].[QIP_Subnet] AS Q ON SP.KeyHash = Q.__key_Hash; PRINT @result ;SET NoCount OFF; "
Write-Host $unassignedCnt
```